# How python implements concatenation?

Tags: python, python-3.x

For example, if I try to concatenate three strings together with the `+` operator: `s = "s1" + "s2" + "s3"`, how does python handle it?
Will it calculate len1, len2 and then allocate memory for the new string of size len1 + len2 and repeat until all `+` operators are handled?
Or maybe it calculates the length of all operands and performs allocation just once? In this case, is it safe to assume that

```
s = "s1" + "s2" + "s3"
```

will execute faster than

```
s = "s1" + "s2"
s += "s3"
```

Or maybe there is no allocation at all, and it just somehow remembers memory addresses of the operands and their order?
Would appreciate article recommendations on the topic of python optimization.

Comment: Did you mean to say `s = s1 + s2 + s3` where s1, s2 and s3 are variables holding strings?

Comment: Not really... Just regular strings. Does it change something? And thx for the answer), you helped a lot

Comment: You said `"s1" + "s2" + "s3"`, which means we have three string literals with values `s1, s2, s3` whereas `s = s1 + s2 + s3` means s1, s2 and s3 are names holding strings e.g `s1='abcd', s2 = 'efgh'` etc

Comment: Both examples fully depict the question, and are interchangeable, cos in this case nothing changes

Comment: Sure, that clarified it, thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As per the [source](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/unicodeobject.c#L11264) here, looks like it does calculate the length of both strings, and then create a new string with length equal to the sum of new lengths

```
left_len = PyUnicode_GET_LENGTH(left);
right_len = PyUnicode_GET_LENGTH(right);
if (left_len > PY_SSIZE_T_MAX - right_len) {
    PyErr_SetString(PyExc_OverflowError,
                    "strings are too large to concat");
    return NULL;
}
new_len = left_len + right_len;

maxchar = PyUnicode_MAX_CHAR_VALUE(left);
maxchar2 = PyUnicode_MAX_CHAR_VALUE(right);
maxchar = Py_MAX(maxchar, maxchar2);
/* Concat the two Unicode strings */
result = PyUnicode_New(new_len, maxchar);
```

For three strings, It concatenates the first two strings, and then concatenate the result to the third string.

When you disassemble the function via [dis.dis](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dis.html#dis.dis), you can see that the [BINARY_ADD](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dis.html#opcode-BINARY_ADD) opcode, which is the string concatenation operation with the overloaded `+` is done for `s1` and `s2` and then on the result of the previous operation with `s3`

```
In [34]: def f(s1,s2,s3): 
    ...:     return s1+s2+s3 
    ...:                                                                        

In [35]: dis.dis(f)                                                             
  2           0 LOAD_FAST                0 (s1)
              2 LOAD_FAST                1 (s2)
              4 BINARY_ADD
              6 LOAD_FAST                2 (s3)
              8 BINARY_ADD
             10 RETURN_VALUE
```