# How do Python implement `sep.join()` as concatenation of strings?

Tags: python, string

We know we can use `sep.join()` or `+=` to concatenate strings. For example,

```
a = ["123f", "asd", "y]
print("".join(a))
# output: 1234asdy
```

In Java, stringbuilder would creat a new string, and put the two string on the both sides of plus together, so it will cost `O(n^2)`. But in Python, how will `join` method do for multiway merge?
A similar question is [How python implements concatenation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56522126/how-python-implements-concatenation) It explains `+=` for two way merge.

Comment: Java's stringbuilder takes O(n²) for that? Geez, Java sucks even more than I thought.

Answer (score 1):

for cpython version 3.X you can see the source code [here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Objects/stringlib/join.h) and it does indeed calculate the total length beforehand and only does 1 allocation.

On a side note, if your application is limited by the speed of joining strings such that you have to think about join implementation then you shouldn't be using python, and instead go for c++.

Comment: Sounds like they're worried about quadratic runtime of join and since you make it sound like that's not the case, I don't understand the suggestion to use another language.

Comment: (I.e., that suggestion would be appropriate if they were worried about the speed of *linear* time join, but I don't think they are. And if Java's actually were quadratic, then wondering whether Python is quadratic as well would even be reasonable).

Comment: Although joining strings is done in C, the extra bookkeeping that happens under the hood by python makes it 10-20 times slower than c++, so if this is the longest action in the program that they have to think about its implementation and has to be optimized then c++ is a much better option than python for this project.

Comment: Ok, rereading your *"if your application is limited by the speed of joining strings"*... If that's the case, i.e., if they profiled their code and found out that string joining is too slow, then maybe a faster language would help (Although often a better data structure or algorithm helps far more). But I doubt they profiled and I think string joining being a bottleneck would be rather odd (likely it takes more time to build the strings-to-be-joined).

Answer (score 0):

The operation is O(n). `join` takes an iterable. If its not already a sequence, `join` will create one. Then, using the size of the the separator and the size of each string in the list, a new string object is created. A series of `memcpy` then creates the object. Creating the list, getting the sizes and doing the `memcpy` are all linear.

`+=` is faster and still O(n). A new object the size of the two strings to be concatenated is created, and 2 memcpy do the work. Of course it is only concatenating two strings. If you want to do more, `join` soon becomes the better option.